# Javascript - Average calculation

Tags: javascript, average

Hi I am trying to write a simple calculation that will average the two numbers entered by user input and then click the average button to get the average of the two.  MY problem is that it does not produce an answer. Here is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="one">
<input type="text" id="two">

<input type ="button" onclick="average()"value="average">
<input type="text" id ="avg">
<script type"text/javascript">>
function average(){
    var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("one".value);
    var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("two".value);
    var afinal=((a+b)/2);
        document.getElementById('avg').value=afinal;
    }
</script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe `document.getElementById("one").value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo fix (missing bracket for `getElementById`):

```
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value);
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("two").value);
```

and another typo:

```
<script type"text/javascript">>
```

should be:

```
<script type"text/javascript">
```

so, the final code is:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="one">
    <input type="text" id="two">

    <input type ="button" onclick="average()"value="average">
    <input type="text" id ="avg">
    <script type"text/javascript">
    function average(){
        var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value);
        var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("two").value);
        var afinal=((a+b)/2);
            document.getElementById('avg').value=afinal;
        }
    </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just fixed that and it still does not produce a final number.  The box still remains blank.

Comment: another typo found, updated answer...

Comment: Still no final answer I am very confused as to why it will not show a final number

Comment: Alright thank you then final code worked

Comment: This code works, you must have other error in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo fix,

instead of

```
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("one".value);
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("two".value);
```

the code becomes,

```
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value);
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("two").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the old-school document.getElementById(), consider using an industry-standard, broadly adopted jQuery library, specifically its method called $.

There, you'll be able to use a CSS selector to get to an element that you want. It's extremely powerful, I recommend learning it.

```
var a = $("#one").val();
```